# Express Get api

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm practicing right now with the MEAN stack.

I've made a project with the Angular shell and I've inclueded express in my project.

Here's my first GET, i want to use it to retrive some data from my mongoDB, in this case an entire collection:

```
 router.get('/biscottigrazie', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('biscotti');

});
```

Maybe I'm missing the concept but i think that from angular i should be able to "call" this GET and get the data.

So, my var collection should contain the data, how can I retrive them from angular files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get db instance from request variable. You will get it while you define database.

```
var db = new Db('test', new Server('localhost', 27017));

router.get('/biscottigrazie', function(req, res) {
    var collection = db.getCollection('biscotti');
    res.send(collection);
});
```

Comment: Do you know how can i call this from an angular, and how can i manage the collection?